# Neo4j date and datetime comparison issues

Tags: date, datetime, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've got a very strange behavior of neo4j engine.
Let's assume we have node with date and datetime type properties:

```
merge (n:Item {date: date("2019-10-21"), datetime: datetime("2019-10-21") }  )
return n
```

These queries works fine:

```
match (n:Item)
where n.date>=date("2019-10-20")
return n
```

```
match (n:Item)
where n.datetime>=datetime("2019-10-20")
return n
```

When I try to compare date with datetime (or datetime with date) the empty dataset returns:

```
match (n:Item)
where n.date>=datetime("2019-10-20")
return n
```

```
match (n:Item)
where n.datetime>=date("2019-10-20")
return n
```

Neo4j version is 3.5.11.

Answer (score 3):

In neo4j, you cannot directly compare temporal values of different types (e.g., `date` and `datetime`).

1. With your use case, you could convert the `date` to a `datetime` before doing the comparison.

   For example, your last 2 queries could convert the `date` to a `datetime`:

   ```
   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE datetime({date:n.date}) >= datetime("2019-10-20")
   RETURN n;


   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE n.datetime >= datetime({date:date("2019-10-20")})
   RETURN n;
   ```
2. But with your use case it would also be valid (and perhaps more efficient)  to convert the `datetime` to a `date` (notice that is is OK to pass a `datetime` as the `date` property value):

   ```
   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE n.date >= date({date: datetime("2019-10-20")})
   RETURN n;


   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE date({date: n.datetime}) >= date("2019-10-20")
   RETURN n;
   ```
3. Yet another approach is to compare the `year` and `ordinalDay` values, as in:

   ```
   WITH datetime("2019-10-20") AS dt
   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE n.date.year >= dt.year AND n.date.ordinalDay >= dt.ordinalDay
   RETURN n;

   WITH date("2019-10-20") AS d
   MATCH (n:Item)
   WHERE n.datetime.year >= d.year AND n.datetime.ordinalDay >= d.ordinalDay
   RETURN n;
   ```